# Novice awareness of the accept feature

Tags: discussion, reputation, accepted-answer

True, [accepting an answer is entirely optional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=accept%20the%20answer%20tip), yet a number of novice askers [seem to be genuinely unaware of the feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491374/specify-a-folder-to-save-screenshots-to-in-desktopmagic/26491765#comment41618595_26491765) and its importance.

I haven't seen many of these though - maybe, 3 or 4 throughout my career (166 answers as of now) who explicitly said they're satisfied but didn't accept the answer or did so after pointing out this opportunity.

So, the questions are:

- **Is this a sizable problem?**
- **If it is, what could help raise the awareness?**
  (Specifically, I thought about a tip somewhere around the asking window, with thought-out placement and wording)

A side-question is:

- Is this a sizable problem **throughout the network?** (if it is, the question needs to be moved to MSE)

Comment: If your answer was enough for a newbie and he went away, there is nothing you can do (pressing mods to send an e-mail reminder sounds a bit as overkill...). But if he came back to post a "thank you", I'd leave a comment stating that "thanks are appreciated but the *correct* procedure is .. (link to Help)". People only asking once then going away bothers me but I don't think there is a solution.

Comment: No, it is not a sizable problem. Most people want to do the right thing and a gentle reminder (only if the user is new and has not accepted answers before!) is usually enough. About 70% of my answers have been marked accepted, and I'd say that only a very small portion of the remaining 30% are posts where the OP has thanked me for my answer but then did not mark it as accepted (the rest are answers where another answer was given that was accepted or the OP was not happy with the result).

Comment: And to be 100% clear about this: **This is fine** and doesn't need any further poking.

Comment: On the rep side, it doesn't matter much, it's easy to whore rep on this site anyway due to the many help vampires.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, I did a search over prior discussions and found nothing so dunno what you mean by "further poking".

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: further poking of people to accept answers. There is a lot of prior discussion on [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'll still publish the statistics before closing this.

Comment: We could display a little notice on a user's profile card if they don't accept very many answers. Maybe make it red if it's too bad. This would make sure they realize they're doing something wrong, and would let potential answers know what they're getting into. I bet we'd see a quick improvement in "accept rate" with this simple change.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194070/144883

Comment: @Jeremy not sure if serious... We used to have that, and people were pestering OPs with comments like _"Accept answers on your older questions first"_.

Comment: My suggestion is to place a prominent tip _under the tick_ (probably a dismissable text balloon with the protrusion pointing at the tick) with text like: _"accept a single answer if you are satisfied with it"._ The tip would only show for users w/o accepted answers (and probably if they didn't dismiss it before). In any case, this needs to be consistent with other tips we give (do we?).

Comment: To me whether or not it's a *sizeable* problem, it's a really *freaking annoying problem* when the author states that the answer solved his problem perfectly in a comment and doesn't accept unless redirected. There's more of a negative, discouraging effect there to the mindset of the people who took the time to provide a really detailed answer when this happens, and that quality which demotivates the answerer is far more profound than numbers can convey, especially for those who are trying to be the precise opposite of the FGITW.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Bottom line: 17% of all users with no more than 8 questions appear to be unaware. The figure likely includes abandoned questions that were not caught by automatic deletion** (the ones where the OP didn't care rather than (or as well as) didn't know).

---

Here's the derivation.

1. [Users without any accepted answers vs all users with the same number of questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/398384/users-without-accepted-answers#graph). It only counts Q&As

- with answers, and
- with last edit of any post (creation time if a post was never edited) older than 3 months (to exclude those that might be in a transient state), and
- non-closed questions (closed ones are presumed to be invalid for the purpose of this research).

Y axis has logarithmic scale save for the ratio curve.
X is the number of questions (subject to the above restrictions) a user has.

[image: fig.1]

A whopping 65% of users with 1 question! But that includes questions that are unaccepted for other reasons. Which we'll now be filtering out.

2. Many of these are likely to be legitimately unaccepted. Let's see [the percentage of unaccepted questions for users who are knowingly aware of the feature](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/398032/legitimately-unanswered-questions-vs-score#graph) (i.e. have at least one accepted question). The sampling is done

- in correlation with question score - there's likely to be a big difference, so averaging everything out blindly is a bad idea
- subject to the same restrictions as above

[image: fig.2]

As you can see, the ratio is never greater than 35%. Let's take 35% for all to make a conservative estimation.

3. [Added to the graph 1](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/397295/users-without-accepted-answers#graph)

- "users' worth of legitimately unaccepted questions". Since questions per user is constant for each sample, the amount to cut is "legit_share/QperU of the total number"
- new ratio: "`max(0,unaccepted-legit)/total`"

[image: fig.3]

To be honest, the cut-off share is far more than I expected. In particular, everything after 8 questions is cut off completely (this doesn't mean those users do not exist, this means they are statistically insignificant, given our assumptions).

4. Some questions can be abandoned ones that [the automatic deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) didn't detect. E.g. a partial (or even full) answer was given, and the OP went away not because it's bad but rather because they didn't care (e.g. they found a solution on their own and didn't care to post and accept it). I've no idea how to filter these out (yet).
5. I don't see any more possible irrelevant reasons. So, now we can [compute the bottom line](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/398383/conservative-estimate-of-users-unaware-of-accept-feature): the percentage of the presumed unaware users from all the newbies.

   ```
    | UnawareUsers       | TotalNoviceUsers | Ratio               |
    |--------------------|------------------|---------------------|
    | 301702.88541667664 | 1724308          | 0.17497041445999012 |
   ```

This is in agreement with `15%` produced in [the previous answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276877/648265).

Comment: Yes, you filtered on age, sorry. Still, does ignoring downvoted answers change anything?

Comment: @Deduplicator negative-scored answers aren't necessarily unsatisfactory for an OP, so this is a bad criterion.

Comment: There has been no criticism about the research's or result's validity, so I'm accepting this as the ultimate answer to the matter in question.

Answer (score -4):

Comments have unanimously shown this is not much enough of a problem to need addressing.

The full statistics on my SO account (~3k rep with 166 answers over 3 3/4 years) are:

- 4 answers where OPs explicitly stated their satisfaction

  - 2 of them accepted them when pointed to the feature
- 22 answers that apparently addressed the problem for an OP¹

  - of which about 15 that I'm confident they did

I couldn't find any research results to say how this corresponds to the general percentage of new contributors who do not take time to learn a community's workings before trying to participate.

¹Tried to be objective. This means one was: 1) either a solution for everything asked or a critical step towards one if the former wasn't possible with the info given; 2) either the only answer or others were few and lacking 1) beyond doubt (and were not accepted either, of course); 3) OP's behaviour showed they likely got what they needed and clearly didn't combine it from multiple answers.

Comment: To develop a meaningful statistic, I think we'd also need to know when someone else was the [fastest gun in the west](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/173448). The fastest gun with an equivalent answer would probably mean your 15/22 statistic is not what it appears.

Comment: @jww I didn't count such cases as well as any where there is an accepted answer. Thought that goes without saying when i "try to be objective".

Comment: If I correctly understand you are saying that about 16% of the questions on which you answered were never accepted ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta 24/166≈0.145 . It's not me, it's the statistics that says so. Since the information is public, you're free to verify it.

Comment: I counted (22 + 4)/166. As it was on different lines it was not evident to me what was part of what ... and that's the reason why I asked the question :-) But now I can understand that 2 on the 4 were actually accepted so the total of 24 and a result of about 15% ...

Comment: I think you should head over to http://data.stackexchange.com/ and get some more conclusive data.. I've found that most newbies dont even know to tick it or that it gives them points or thats its the way to signal their question has been answered.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(user questions) as c FROM ... WHERE c < 3 AND votetypeid = XYZ
Something like that.. to indicate user has never accepted and could be unaware. Graph the results!