# Encourage users to accept answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In the past few days I finally had some time off work and started answering more questions on SO (mostly iOS). While doing that I stumbled upon a few users that have already asked a couple of question (5+) and did not accept any answer while some answer clearly solved the problem as the OP sometimes even says in a comment. I do not like this behavior/situation. I think these kind of situations arise from a lack of knowledge (about SO and the ask-answer-workflow) or ignorance or simply the user forgetting about the answer. He got the help he needed and is off to some place else.

The latest example is [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4671001). Since he accepted a few answers I would guess option 3 is what happened here. I stumbled upon him in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34422578) and am currently waiting if he will accept my answer (even if the question is closed by now).

Note that I am talking about relatively active users, nothing we can about users who visit one time only and ask a question and are off forever.

My question is now wether or not there is some kind of reminder system implemented that tells users to check back on their question containing answers where the acceptance is missing. Or if such a system has been actively thought about and discarded?

In regards to how such a system might work I was thinking about reminding the user

- from time to time
- when he accepts an answer that there are still other un-accepted questions
- when he asks a new question
- when one of his answers gets accepted

Or even more strictly disallowing any more asking of questions all together until he changed the situation.

Of course there would have to some way to remember that a user actively chose not to accept an answer, e.g. if the answers given simply did not solve the problem.

Comment: I support this - I can never understand why people post questions and keep them open forever even when their is a good answer.  Its like having open issues sitting around.  Here's the unfortunate thing, this will be down voted to oblivion...why I dont know.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276871/novice-awareness-of-the-accept-feature

Comment: Were you around when the accept rate percentage was a public stat on user profiles? That led to folks hounding people to accept answers and it turned ugly. [That was removed as a result](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate). Among other bad behaviors, it caused people to randomly accept any answer, even wrong ones, just to stop people badgering them.

Comment: @BradLarson nope, I was not around at that time (at least not active). But that is a result I was already afraid of - that is the exact reason I wrote the last paragraph, if you ask the user ten times to accept an answer while there is no good one he will chose the bad one.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev thank you for the link

Comment: @luk2302 - There might be room for a more gentle reminder, or a one-time educational popup for new users. We know that the public shaming approach didn't work, but maybe another angle would.

Comment: I know of at least one user that only asked questions, never answered, never voted, never accepted, never commented, never flagged, still over 600 rep. Accepting is not mandatory, nor are all the other gamification non-sense.

Comment: I think that the accept mark should just be removed. It is a useless measurement that causes far too many misconceptions about what an answer being accepted means. The user asking the question is usually the least qualified to identify the best answer. The only thing that the accept mark means is that the user asking the question used that answer. Nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: IIRC the system actually reminded me a while back.  I asked a few questions and the next visit to my profile's question tab contained a reminder to accept answers to questions that were actually solved.

Comment: @rene I read that as "I remember that \@BradLarson have done that a lot. That was great fun...."

Comment: @BradLarson I don't see why we can't be encouraging users to accept or close answers that haven't been accepted after X time in private. For example, if a question has been sitting for over a year, has answers but none accepted, and has very little views - in all reality, how useful is that question? I'd be inclined to either encourage the user to accept an answer (if there was one that did help) or the question is automatically closed (depending on it's activity i.e. if it's got quite a number of views then it's a useful question).

Comment: @BradLarson I'd actually argue it's a _good_ thing to pester them, the point of the site is we want to encourage good questions and good answers, and in general build a good community of active users. If we have folk writing questions and providing no feedback, are those really the type of users we want on the site? By doing nothing, then are we not pretty much enabling that type of behaviour. I know it's not uncommon on other platforms to be encouraged to do things when you haven't in a while e.g. update your profile, change your picture, write a post etc.

Comment: It's 2020 now & this is still a great idea!

Answer (score 7):

Accepting is a *privilege* of the OP. Very much similar as I have the privilege to down vote, up vote or close vote posts.

And given those similarities your feature request should be extended:

- ping every user that didn't use all their 40 votes per day
- ping every 3K user that didn't spend all close votes
- ping every user that didn't review their tasks in the queues
- ping those users that didn't use all their delete votes

I expect a lot of pings.

It is really up to the OP to decide if an answer is so well written that it deserves to be accepted. I see not much difference between your proposal and the discussions about the *wrong* answer being accepted. Nobody except the OP can decide what worked best in their scenario. The downside of being the OP is that their action (or the lack of) is visible and with that obviously open for debate. We can even directly nudge the OP in comments. Something we can't do for visitors of the posts who "forget" to (up)vote.

I don't think we need much more features that are already there. If the OP is a regular they will make up their mind somewhere and either accept answers to their questions or they will never do, given the community pressure employed by some of us.

In the end only the up and down votes are important. Those are the real measures for your post quality. The accept mark is a small bonus.

Comment: But none of those pings you're proposing will give me rep.  Some might even *cost* me rep!!!

Comment: I disagree - for me accepting a answer is a duty, not a privilege. Nothing you can or should opt out of. But that is just my opinion :/

Comment: I'm happy to call it a duty if everyone uses all their close votes every day

Comment: SO is designed to encourage people to answer questions. Whenever someone takes the time and makes an effort to do that but gets no response at all, that increases the risk of her becoming frustrated and stop giving her time and effort. As it is good manners to say thank you for a gift, it should be regarded good manners for the OP to accept or comment on answers. And as the elders should educate children on good manners, we should encourage newbies on accepting/commenting. To keep the SO society a helping one.

Comment: @Johanness I beg to differ. Posts have no manners and don't need to be thanked. All voting should be done on the merits of the post, not based on the user attached to it. A good manner would be to accept the answer that helped, not because someone spend time on it. I'm not here to help anyone, I'm here to write answers to good questions. If I want *likes* I go to facebook...

Comment: I agree with @Johanness. It's not the acceptance that counts, it's *some* kind of feedback telling whether the answer was useful or not. For around 50% of my answers, I don't get anything, so I don't know whether I missed the OP's point, delivered a confusing answer, or my solution plainly didn't work. Feedback would also be useful for other visitors of a question. The "unanswered" queues are full of questions that have one or more answers and no feedback on them. Is the OP desparately waiting for the "right" answer, or has he just lost interest in his own question?

Comment: While I understand that it's up to the OP to accept or not an answer, I would like to point out that some users *[never ever accept answers](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/514843/unaccepters)* which is a bit sad...

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Why is that sad? Maybe those users understand perfectly what an accept will do and they rather have the community vote decide which answer should float to the top? Maybe they hope for a better  answer and an accept might scare away potential answers? Or they honestly don't know. I know of at least one user that only asked questions, but never used *any* of the other features (voting/flaging/accepting). The only effect that happened was the (negative) meta effect on their questions because that user was called-out on meta. [relevant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951)

Comment: The simple solution is to remove accept votes entirely.

Comment: If they do it while knowing why the don't accept an answer (whatever the reason is), it's not an issue to me. What makes me (a bit) sad is the part that *honestly don't know*. I feel like we should drive them, at least once to [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and I'm not sure it's the case as of now.

Comment: I discussed it in the tavern and someone pinged a CM so we will know in 6 to 8 if such nudge exist. We did find this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69775/remind-new-users-to-choose-some-answers/69777#69777 but that does require that a user upvotes an answer

Comment: @ThomasAyoub *when looking at your own profile, on main sites only, if you have between 125 and 3000 rep... 
...for each question between 3 and 60 days old with at least 1 answer that isn't closed or bountied... 
...you'll get a message like this:* [Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5107981#5107981)

Comment: As much as I take the point of voting being the real indicator of the "best" answer, as humans, we're brought up and learn on the basis of reward (as a child, you do something good you are rewarded to reinforce that behaviour, as an adult, you do a good job, you get a tip etc). The site is built on that very premise otherwise why have a reputation system or the ability to accept an answer at all? Point being, if people don't get _some_ form of recognition for their efforts then most likely the quality of answers and/or interest in helping others could dwindle.

Comment: Ironic that OP hasn't accepted an answer yet ;)

Comment: @DougRichardson well, the answer itself is at +13/-8 controversial I would say and I'm not kind to the suggestion of the OP. So it is understandable that this answer didn't help them, in which case it is fine to not accept the answer. I wouldn't call that ironic, just a prime example of the SE system at work.