# Might we gently encourage NEW users to distinguish between accepting and upvoting answers?

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, new-users, upvotes

Yes, I know...I'm kinda revisiting [an old request to encourage answer acceptance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313206/encourage-users-to-accept-answers), but in contrast to that question, I'd like to offer that  an upvote is more obvious than accept, and in the case of a new user (marked as such with the "Be Nice" banner) who genuinely doesn't know the difference between an upvote and an accept, it might be worthwhile to prompt with a dialog "Would you like to accept this answer?"...and include a brief contrast between *accept* and *upvote*...and a violin about the angst caused to those poor downtrodden writers-of-self-perceived-good-answers.

I get that automated or enqueued behaviors as described [in this other feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364132/upvote-answers-where-new-users-dont-accept-them-themselves) aren't in keeping with the users' prerogatives to genuinely *appreciate* an answer, but it seems like letting them know the difference is worthwhile. I'm principally talking about the users who haven't even gained the copper shiny coin for reading about asking questions.

Do I really care about the extra 5 points? No! Well yes...I mean...it's a good idea to bring closure, eh? If this seems too...um...beggary, maybe a positive response from said dialog might net only the meager upvote score. I *think* I'm more interested in getting the question rounded out...but maybe I'm only fooling myself.

Anyway, I suspect there are boatloads of single-answer questions where a *new* user upvoted (and maybe even gave a shout-out), but didn't actually accept...principally based on their unfamiliarity with the domain. Seems like a gentle prompt might both inform said new user and relieve the harried serial new-questioner answer-writer.

By all means, I accept the principle that the site is *mostly* for the folks searching for an answer to an immediate need, but I'd propose that such seekers get more from the site when there are more happy question-answerers.

Comment: It's nice to get the +15 you deserve for a good answer, but in the long run accepts don't matter nearly as much as upvotes, the latter is a much better indicator of quality. The best you can do is gently poke the OP to accept an answer after 24 hours. But beyond that, I'd let it go.

Comment: _"I accept the principle that the site is mostly for the benefit of the question-asker"_ This is too inaccurate. The site aims to be mostly for the benefit of visitors, who find a solution to their problem here through a search engine.

Comment: @coldspeed, agreed - a gentle poke is good enough...that's what I'm looking for. But wrt/ the 24-hour thing...they're probably long gone by then...which is my part of my point.

Comment: @E_net4, thanks...I see that's far more appropriate. Edited to reflect your observation.

Comment: I thought we already had this... can't find it though.

Comment: Closely related, albeit over 4 years old: [Novice awareness of the accept feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276871/novice-awareness-of-the-accept-feature)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is already a feature. I just asked a question from a new account last week and when upvoting the first answer that was posted I got a popup with something along the lines of "Don't forget to accept the answer that solved your problem!"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

New users have the ability to accept answer before upvoting. So there's a lot of assumptions in this question I'm not sure are correct. People don't have to accept answers. The site is littered with comments of people asking users to accept their answers. It can border on self serving.

The site is at the brink of being loaded with notifications and UI complications, including the new user indicator. This is totally my opinion and worth just that.  We don't need to be reminded to accept answers. New users or not.

It's not essential to accept an answer. In fact, it's probably preferable to allow the community to float the answers with votes. There's many cases where an accepted answer is deemed "incorrect" and it places a challenge on moderators and the community to deal with it justly and expediently. An accepted answer can only be mod deleted.

> I'm principally talking about the users who haven't even gained the copper shiny coin for RTFMing about asking questions.

Not a nice discourse for a meta question on gently encouraging new users.

Comment: I appreciate your perspective, and anticipated this might be the prevailing view. I suppose frustration got the best of me, and I apologize for the off-color remark.

Comment: *”There's many cases where an accepted answer is deemed "incorrect" and it places a challenge on moderators and the community to deal with it justly and expediently.”* There’s no real challenge. The downvote arrow is only a few millimeters away from the upvote arrow.

Comment: @CodyGray bad answers that have been accepted cannot be deleted by regular users, they require mod deletion, even if they hit the low quality review queue. Plus the accepted answer sits at the top.

Comment: That's obviously by design. If an asker found the answer to be the most helpful of all candidates, then they probably felt that way for a reason, and its deletion shouldn't be taken lightly. The community is not powerless. A large number of downvotes still cause it to be greyed out, an obvious indicator that the viewer should look elsewhere. Such as, immediately below it.